# XLSX (SheetJs) Export excel file corrupt when deployed in Production (Vercel)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, xlsx, vercel, file-saver

I'm implementing xlsx libray using `xlsx-js-style` which is forked from `sheetjs` and `file-saver` for saving the xlsx file. Export to excel functionality works fine in local development but when deployed to production e.g vercel the downloaded excel file cant open:

**Error when opening SS:**

[image]

**Code Snippet SS:**

```
  import { utils, WorkSheet, write } from "xlsx-js-style";
  import { saveAs } from "file-saver";

  const exportToCSV = () => {
    // Initialize new Book
    const wb = utils.book_new();

    // Iterate SObject and create new sheet per SObject.
    Object.keys(sObjectsWithDetailsData).forEach((key) => {
        if (!sObjectsWithDetailsData[key]) return;

        // Filter Rows Data
        const rows = sObjectsWithDetailsData[key]?.map((row) => ({
            "R/O": row.updateable ? "✓" : "☐",
            R: !row.nillable ? "*" : "",
            label: row.label ?? "",
            name: row.name ?? "",
            fieldDescription: row.fieldDescription ?? "",
            inlineHelpText: row.inlineHelpText ?? "",
            custom: row.custom ?? false,
            externalId: row.externalId ?? false,
            type: row.type ?? "",
            calculatedFormula: row.calculatedFormula ?? "",
            picklistValues:
                row.picklistValues
                    ?.map((picklist) => picklist.label)
                    .join("\n") ?? "",
        }));

        const ws = utils.json_to_sheet(rows ?? []);

        // Modify Header Names
        utils.sheet_add_aoa(
            ws,
            [
                [
                    "R/O",
                    "M",
                    "Label",
                    "API Name",
                    "Description",
                    "HelpText",
                    "Is Custom",
                    "Is External ID",
                    "Type",
                    "Formula Text",
                    "Picklist Values",
                ],
            ],
            {
                origin: "A1",
            }
        );

        utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, key);
    });

    // Execute export
    const wbout = write(wb, { bookType: "xlsx", type: "binary" });
    saveAs(
        new Blob([s2ab(wbout)], { type: "application/octet-stream" }),
        "test.xlsx"
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned Vercel, so I assume you are using Next.js. You might have to turn off the SWC minifier, see https://docs.sheetjs.com/docs/miscellany/errors/#corrupt-files